# Developing android soft keyboard: sample doesn't implement change of form fields correctly

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I tried the soft keyboard from scratch and I found an issue when I press the *Next* button. It works as expected on other keyboards, so I think maybe it’s something that they didn’t think about when developing the sample. I didn’t try on other versions yet.

Version used: Android API 15
Source code from android-sdk/samples/android-15/SoftKeyboard

The problem: If you have a form with two text fields, after pushing the next button (the enter one at the bottom right), the cursor doesn't go to the next field.

Example: It’s possible to try using the contacts app:

- Open contacts
- Click some contact
- Click the edit button at the top in the action bar
- Look at the contact's emails, if there is only one text field press the + button so there are at least 2 text fields
- Click the first text field to edit email #1
- Type the next button on soft keyboard sample
- The cursor will disappear and it won't go to the next field
  (sometimes it crashes, but usually you can just touch the text field
  again and everything goes normal)

While debugging I didn’t found any problem yet, but I had some places in the source code to look around:
At the `com.example.android.softkeyboard.SoftKeyboard` class:

At the `public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` method there is:

```
case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
// Let the underlying text editor always handle these.
return false;
```

I looked upon it, while debugging it falls here and it looks alright, because the cursor change is not to be handled by the soft keyboard

Another method that I thought about is

```
public void onStartInput(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting)
```

Maybe it isn’t getting the cursor where it is so it just vanishes. But I couldn’t find a way to that yet so I don’t know if it is really what’s happenning.